# GAE Refreshing due to a 401 (attempt 1/2)

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-platform, google-authentication

i deploy an app using gcloud app deploy. It runs fine for couple of hours and then the jobs get stuck with following info log :

```
03:54:59.748 Refreshing due to a 401 (attempt 1/2)
03:58:44.816 Refreshing due to a 401 (attempt 1/2)
03:58:55.781 Refreshing due to a 401 (attempt 1/2)
03:58:56.317 Refreshing due to a 401 (attempt 1/2)
```

Seems like it is being logged from internal serviceName: "appengine.googleapis.com"

The app deployed reads some file from GCS and publishes some computed metrics using google pubsub. I use google client api  library which uses credentials to authenticate.

```
    credentials = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()
    if credentials.create_scoped_required():
        credentials = credentials.create_scoped(['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_only)
    http = httplib2.Http()
    credentials.authorize(http)
    return discovery.build('storage', 'v1', http=http)
```

Similar snippet for pubsub as well. Has any one run into similar issue where the request seems to be stuck forever with info logs showing 401 status code. Not sure why doesn't the request just times out and results in failure . any workarounds ?

Comment: Any specific reason for not using the recommended [Google Cloud idiomatic libraries](https://cloud.google.com/apis/docs/cloud-client-libraries)?

Answer (score 2):

401 is unauthorized error, this means that the OAuth bearer token is no longer valid and needs to be refreshed using the refresh token. The timelines you explain match with [the duration of the bearer tokens](https://www.oauth.com/oauth2-servers/access-tokens/access-token-lifetime/).

I would use the [cloud idiomatic libraries](https://cloud.google.com/apis/docs/cloud-client-libraries), or if you are using GAE standard, [the appengine libraries directly](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/refdocs/). Those libraries handle authentication themselves (including refreshing the tokens when they expire), and include further optimizations for using within App Engine.

Answer (score -1):

This one was a headache for me but I get it now.

In my app I want to scan my emails for keywords to get the top most paypal receipt. Of course I will not reveal my full mechanics but I have provided more than necessary for context and usage. I have a personal account I have renamed paypalEmailAccount@gmail.com and a api admin account renamed office@myBusiness.com and website I have renamed www.myBusiness.com. I do not want to risk exposing any exploit accidentally.

```
class Quickbooks(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.post()
    def post(self):
        ping(self)
        user = users.get_current_user()
        if (levelOneUsers( user ) or levelTwoUsers( user )):
            nameField = self.request.get('pName')
            if nameField == 'e':
                categoryLevel=0;
                service = getUserGmail(self, 'paypalEmailAccount@gmail.com@gmail.com')
                userName = 'paypalEmailAccount@gmail.com'
                if( service ):
                    officeDriveService = getOfficeDrive()
                    topMessage = getTopMessage( service, officeDriveService, 'in:inbox service@paypal.com' )
    (main code then processes topMessage, no need to see any of that.....lol)

def getUserGmail(self, emailAddress):
    if(emailAddress=='office@myBusiness.com'): 
        return getOfficeGmail()
    else:
        creds_query = Creds.query(ancestor=credsCounter_key(DEFAULT_CREDS_NAME)).order(-Creds.number)
        creds_query2 = creds_query.filter(Creds.number==emailAddress)
        creds_items = creds_query2.fetch(1)
        for creds_item in creds_items:
            jsonCreds = creds_item.jsonString
            check = json.loads(jsonCreds)
            token_info = urllib.urlopen("https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/tokeninfo?access_token=" + check['access_token'])
            token_info_dict = json.loads(token_info.read())
            if( 'expires_in' in token_info_dict and token_info_dict['expires_in'] > 0 ):
                credentials = OAuth2Credentials.from_json(jsonCreds)
                http_auth = credentials.authorize(Http())
                keepTrying = True
                tryCounter = 0
                while keepTrying:
                    try:
                        tryCounter += 1
                        service = build('gmail', 'v1', http=http_auth)
                    except:
                        time.sleep(1)
                        if (tryCounter >= 10):
                            raise
                    else:
                        keepTrying = False
                return service
        flow = OAuth2WebServerFlow(client_id='???????????-??????????????????????????????????.apps.googleusercontent.com',
                               client_secret='?????????????????????',
                               scope='https://mail.google.com/', 
                               redirect_uri='https://www.myBusiness.com.com/auth_return',
                               login_hint=emailAddress)
        flow.params['access_type'] = 'offline'
        auth_uri = flow.step1_get_authorize_url()
        self.redirect(auth_uri)

class Auth_Return(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.post()
    def post(self):
        ping(self)
        code = nameField = self.request.get('code')
        flow = OAuth2WebServerFlow(client_id='?????????????-?????????????????????????.apps.googleusercontent.com',
                           client_secret='??????????????????',
                           scope='https://mail.google.com/', 
                           redirect_uri='https://www.myBusiness.com.com/auth_return')
        flow.params['access_type'] = 'offline'
        credentials = flow.step2_exchange(code)
        jsonCred = credentials.to_json()
        http_auth = credentials.authorize(Http())
        keepTrying = True
        tryCounter = 0
        while keepTrying:
            try:
                tryCounter += 1
                service = build('gmail', 'v1', http=http_auth)
            except:
                time.sleep(1)
                if (tryCounter >= 10):
                    raise
            else:
                keepTrying = False
        response = service.users().getProfile(userId="me").execute()
        creds_query = Creds.query(ancestor=credsCounter_key(DEFAULT_CREDS_NAME)).order(-Creds.number)
        creds_query2 = creds_query.filter(Creds.number==response['emailAddress'])
        creds_items = creds_query2.fetch(1)
        if(len(creds_items) == 0):
            creds_item = Creds(parent=credsCounter_key(DEFAULT_CREDS_NAME))
            creds_item.number = response['emailAddress']
            creds_item.jsonString = jsonCred
            creds_item.put()
        else:
            for creds_item in creds_items:
                creds_item.jsonString = jsonCred
                creds_item.put()
        self.response.write('<b name="handshake_complete">A security handshake between server and email address: ' + response['emailAddress'] +  ' was required to continue. This is usually due to an expired certificate. This caused the previous request to be lost but the system will redirect back in 1 second...please wait.... A secure connection has been established.</b><br>' + """
<script>
window.location = "https://www.myBusiness.com/quickbooks?pName=????????";
</script>
""")

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/', MainPageBlank ),
    ('/quickbooks', Quickbooks),
    ('/auth_return', Auth_Return),
    .......
], debug=True)
```

OK....so that's a lot but there is just one line to examine....the rest is context for your amusement. And don't criticize me on anything...aint gonna hear it....I am the GREATEST

```
if( 'expires_in' in token_info_dict and token_info_dict['expires_in'] > 0
```

token_info_dict['expires_in'] IS MEASURED IN SECONDS, WHEN 'FRESH' IT IS 3600 (1 HOUR)
per: [Microsoft's Manage access tokens for API requests](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/machine-learning-server/operationalize/how-to-manage-access-tokens)

Well, that's a problem. The google api thread instance is limited to 60 seconds. If token_info_dict['expires_in'] is less than 60 but greater than 0 then the code can fail while processing requests in that 60 second interval. Plus the error has at most 1/60 chance of occurring making it very hard to pin down.

SOLUTION:

```
if( 'expires_in' in token_info_dict and token_info_dict['expires_in'] > 60
```

Now the token will not expire before the google api thread time limit